# simple python converting miles to kilo loop

Tags: python, loops

I need some help with setting up a simple mile to kilo python loop. I need to make a list of miles, run it through a loop that converts that list to kilometers, then prints the list of kilometers.

I have been at this since yesterday and python just keeps crapping on me. I went back to the book i am learning out of "Zelles Python programming third edition" and goes over looping lists but not so much converting, or maybe it does and i am just not seeing it.

Anyways here is my code that I have so far. Its probably really jacked up but what can I do other than just keep trying to figure this out and get it right?

Anyways thanks for looking!

```
    def main():
        mileINk = 1.609344
        miles = [0,1,2,3,4]
        kilo = []
        for mileINk in miles:
            conV = eval(mileINk * miles)
            kilo.append(chr(conV))
        print(round(kilo, 3))

    main()
```

Comment: Does it have to be formatted like this? I think there are some easier ways to do this in python

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: Can you add the error message your code is "crapping out"?

Comment: used eval because of some errors i was getting, I worked on this a bit and will update the code.

Comment: And it doesnt have to be formatted like this. just keep in mind i am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a bit wrong with your syntax. Looping is a little different in python. You don't make an arithmetic sequence like in other languages, you iterate over each element; if that makes sense.

So a for loop is this:

```
for new_temp_variable in iterable_object:
  do stuff
```

So you want

```
for mile in miles:
  do computation
```

You don't need to do an eval on multiplication. You shouldn't convert to a character using chr. You also can't round a list.

Ultimately I recommend reading a python tutorial or a different tutorial, as it seems you don't have a firm grasp of the syntax

If your ok with some new syntax you could use a list comprehension. Its syntax that makes doing stuff like this easier. I.E.

```
def main():
  mileINk = 1.609344
  miles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  kilo = [mileINk * each for each in miles]
  print(kilo)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time! I was going back and forth in the book which resulted in my code getting a little chopped up. But I learned what I was doing wrong and got a better understanding of basically what I should have been doing. I got pretty close a few times but still not getting the desired output. anyways thanks again and many cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
kilo = [ m * mileINk for m in miles ]
Print(kilo)
```

This uses a list comprehension which compressed a for loop on a list into one line.

After the changes to your code:

```
def main():
    mileINk = 1.609344
    miles = [0,1,2,3,4]
    kilo = [ m * mileINk for m in miles ]
    print(kilo)
main()
```

Note:
best-practice with python would use magic methods like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mileINk = 1.609344
    miles = [0,1,2,3,4]
    kilo = [ m * mileINk for m in miles ]
    print(kilo)
```

Comment: Suggesting a list comprehension probably isn't going to help a total beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many errors. Here is it fixed:

```
def main():
    mileINk = 1.609344
    miles = [0,1,2,3,4]
    kilo = []
    for mile in miles:
        conV = mile * mileINk
        conV = round(conV, 3)
        kilo.append(conV)
    print(kilo)

main()
```

**Output**: `[0.0, 1.609, 3.219, 4.828, 6.437]`

Here are the errors found in your code:

- You are using the **same variable name** `mileINk` for storing `1.609344` and in the `for` loop. This is an obvious one.
- `eval` takes a **string** as an argument; `mileINk * miles` will throw an error. I don't think that you need `eval`
- Inside the `for` loop, you are multiplying with `miles`, while you should multiply **with every item** in `miles`.
- `chr` is used to return the **unicode representation** of a number. You diffidently don't need it here.
- `round` takes **a number not a list** (in your case, `kilo`).

Your problem can be solved in a more "Pythonic" ways, but I kept things simple, so you don't get confused.

Comment: Thank you! yeah as i went back and forth in the book, i started trying many different things which well ended up in more errors which also kept throwing me off. So the eval and chr were from me just trying different things out and along the way my code got pretty chopped up. I am  not really understanding the second loop? I believe that is to get all 5 conversions to show up together on the output? Can that be done inside the same loop? I think that is what i was trying to do. but again thank you very much for your help! bravo!

Comment: Welcome. The second loop was to round the resulted numbers, so `1.124325` becomes `1.124`, and yes, this operation is better be inside the first loop, so I've edited my answer. Finally, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand the iterator very clearly, or something else.

```
for mileINk in miles:
```

In each iteration of the above statement, Python assess one element in miles to mileINk. Thus, mileINk not equals to 1.609344 anymore, but equals to 0,1,2,3,4 in each iteration.
Changing the statement to

```
for mile in miles:
    conV = mileINk * mile
    kilo.append(str(conV))
```

is ok.